# Is Windows Server OS required for deploying Application Center

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-appcenter

I am new to the IBM Mobilefirst platform. I want to install the Application center on my machine via the IBM installation manager. I currently have Windows 7 Professional OS installed on my machine.

I referred the below link from OS Pre-requisites -

http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/osForProduct?deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88#osFamily-2

Here it mentions that i need a Windows Server 2012 R2 standard edition to install application center.

I don't have this setup and i only need to access the application center for my understanding and evaluation purpose. So i have 2 questions to ask -

1. Do i ONLY need a Windows Server machine to install Application Center?
2. If yes, than is there some place i can get a free demo of the application center for evaluation purpose?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is no free demo available...

I'm pretty sure you can also install it on Windows 7.
The suggested setup is for production use.

Comment: Idan thanks for your response. Kindly refer this report for Windows 7 professional -http://www-969.ibm.com/software/reports/compatibility/clarity-reports/report/html/osTabViewDetails?dsrType=tsr&deliverableId=46183B706BEA11E48038141DE954FC88&osFamily=Windows&osId=1235160765373&product=IBM+MobileFirst+Platform+Foundation+7.1&isDUOnly=undefined&osDisplay=Windows+7++Professional+x86-32&compIds=D008%7CD005%7CD003%7CD002%7CS007%7CS010%7CS009%7CS011%7CS004%7CS001%7CM006  under components tab it says that Application center is not supported.

Comment: Okay, then you have your answer.